# Tkinter Python3 Insert table with pack

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I found this example for have multiple page on TKinter and I was trying to use it but I got a problem, in the first page I want a table that return to me some value that I read from the DB, the problem is that the code that I found use the pack() so I can't get columns and row....

Is there someone that know with pack how to introduce a table? I try to search but I didn't find too much.

```
TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
text_font = ("Helvetica", 14)

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(10, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Home", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Users",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Courses",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack(side="left")
        button2.pack(side="left")
        #########################
        #I want Introduce my table here with 9 columns and dynamic lines
        #########################

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="User Page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Courses Page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

I was trying something like that but the problem is that give me error every time on the grid command:

```
for j in range(10):
    for i in range(10):
        e = tkinter.Entry(f)
        e.grid(column=i,row=j, borderwidth=0)
        es[i,j] = e
```

Comment: what error ? Always put in questio full error message. There are other usefull information.

Comment: BTW: you can put `Frame()` using `pack()` and inside this frame you can put widgets using `grid()`. You can even put another `Frame` and inside this frame you can again use `pack()`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just switch the `pack` calls to `grid` in that one page? There's nothing preventing you from doing that.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley I didn;t know it was possible, I'm new of Tkinter, some advice of how to do please?

Comment: @furas when I run my code with the grid I receive this error: bad option "-borderwidth": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky

Comment: `borderwidth` is option which you can use in `Frame()`, `Label()`, `Button()`, etc. but not in `grid()` - ie `Label(borderwidth=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page you can put `Frame()` using `pack()` and then inside this frame you can put your table using `grid()`.

Comment: How do I put a Frame inside of a pack?

Comment: `your_frame.pack()`. And later you can put elements inside this frame using `grid()` - ie. `Label(your_frame, ...).grid()`